# How to localize and internationalize C project with ICU?

Tags: c, internationalization, icu

I'm interested in ICU's internationalization and I wanna see if it's OK to integrate it with a C project.

I've read the documentation in its website (localizing[1](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/localizing)) (resource management[2](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/resources#TOC-Resource-Bundle-APIs)). And I found it not as easy as gettext. However, I'm still wondering how fit ICU is for a C project's internationalization.

Is there anybody experienced with it? It's great if you have code. :-)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you cannot use ICU and gettext at the same time? ICU is not necessary the best choice for String Externalization, but it might be the right choice for other things.

Comment: @PawełDyda, I just want to try ICU's internationalization support.

Comment: I work on ICU so I won't make this an answer, but there's sample code in `icu/source/samples/uresb/` and elsewhere